# Access value before it's converted by an attribute accessor

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have an accessor on my model for a boolean column:

```
public function getActiveAttribute($value)
    {
        if ($value == 0) {
            return "No";
        } else {
            return "Yes";
        }
    }
```

The problem I am having is the corresponding form input, a radio button, does not have either options selected when I go to a create or edit view. I could amend the form so the values of the radio buttons are "Yes" and "No" and then write a mutator for the same field.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you just want to leave the existing `active` attribute alone, so you can access the raw value, but create an accessor for display purposes.

So, rename your accessor to `getActiveYesNoAttribute()`, and then your boolean will be available as `active`, and your Yes/No will be available as `active_yes_no`.

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function getActiveYesNoAttribute()
    {
        return $this->active ? "Yes" : "No";
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$user = \App\User::first();

dd($user->active, $user->active_yes_no);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, although I'd call the accessor `getActiveLabelAttribute` in case you decide to change the label values.

Comment: @Rob It's up to the OP, but I went very specific because we don't know the OP's use cases. It might be appropriate just to call it a label, but there could also be another place where the user wants to show "Y/N" (`getActiveYNAttribute()`, and another place where the user wants to show "0/1" (`getActiveZeroOneAttribute()`), and another place where the user wants to show unicode for a check/x (`getActiveCheckXAttribute()`), where each one is considered a label, just different uses. I'd also suggest moving this out to a Presenter, but that's getting beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Fair call. But if the above was the case, I'd suggest creating a method that accepted some form of input flag for that, rather than an accessor. I see your point though.

Comment: @Rob Well, accessors can't accept additional input parameters, so if you wanted to use accessors, you'd have to stick with the individual methods. But, if you were okay with not using accessors, you could definitely create a new method that accepted an input flag and returned the expected output.

Comment: I know, that's why I said a method, rather than an accessor.

Comment: @Rob Ah, sorry, I missed the "rather than an accessor" part. Sounds good. I apologize if it feels as if I'm going over something basic, it's just hard to gauge a person's knowledge of the framework over a couple quick comments. And it's even harder when you misread those comments. :)

Comment: No worries, cheers for the apology :)

Comment: @patricus thanks for the answer. I've just tried your sample code and it always returns "No", even when the value is TRUE

Comment: @showFocus Ah, sorry about that. When you change the name of the function, the `active` value no longer comes in through the `$value` parameter. You have to change the function to look at the active value. I have updated the code in the answer, and that should work for you.

Comment: @patricus Thank you, this works. I've accepted your answer. Where can I dig in to the framework to understand why this works?

Comment: @showFocus You'll want to start with the `__get()` magic method on the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` object.